# AES algorithm implementation in C

Tags: c, aes

Can anyone share me AES algorithm code with Input and Key details in C, i have checked this link https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-c/blob/master/aes.c, but couldn't conclude as it not has the main() function.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the proper way to call it:

```
struct AES_ctx ctx;
AES_init_ctx(&ctx, key);

for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
  AES_ECB_encrypt(&ctx, plain_text + (i * 16));
  phex(plain_text + (i * 16));
}
```

You may check other details in the following file from the same repository:
https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-c/blob/master/test.c

Answer (score 1):

Check AES implementation in OpenSSL: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/aes/aes_core.c

Comment: Thanks , Could you share me the main() as well, wanted to see what's the input, and other details

Comment: The AES core is not directly used in the main program. You should , first, specify the block cipher mode (e.g. ECB, CBC,...). Then, it will be possible to call the related functions. I think scrolling through the code of speed tests [https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/speed.c ] would be helpful. However, if you are looking for test vectors, visit the NIST Cryptographic Algorithm Validation Program (CAVP) at [https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-algorithm-validation-program ].